# How to "exit" from a WebAssembly process on the front-end?

Tags: webassembly

I'm writing a webassembly compiler that currently uses a node.js runtime. My code does error checks which call a javascript error handler that basically does:

```
function error(errCode) {
    console.error("Some error message")
    process.exit(1)
}
```

which I call in webassembly like:

```
(i32.const my_error_code)
(call $error)
```

Is there an equivalent front-end function I can use to halt the current webassembly process?

Answer (score 1):

No - WebAssembly does NOT run in its own process. WebAssembly is a part of JS, meaning that WASM is in the same context as your JS context. So terminating its process doesn't make sense. It only emulate exit() function just like you posted.

WASM being part of JS is important to understand how WASM works. In a web browser, WASM can only interact with JS API for system-related features. It doesn't have concept of process, nor it doesn't have native threads. Threads in WASM world are emulated using JS' Web Workers.